# how to add or subtract value exactly by 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

i have some values in array. assume the values i am using for like and dislike options as in facebook. user can give only 1 like or 1 dislike. if disliked, like becomes 0 and if liked, dislike becomes 0.

1. like and dislike numbers should not give negative values. -ve value should be rounded to 0.
2. for like = 24 & dislike = 0 : user can select like or dislike only one time. i.e., when like is selected - like is 25 & dislike remains same as 0. if dislike is selected, like becomes 24 and dislike remains 0. but value 24 should not reach to 26 at all.
3. for like = 0 and dislike = 15 : when user selects like, like becomes 1 and dislike becomes 14. again if dislike is selected, dislike becomes 15 and like becomes 0.
4. for like=32 & dislike=12: if user selects like, like becomes 33 and dislike becomes 11. again if user selects dislike, dislike becomes 12 and like becomes 32. again now if the user selects like, like becomes to 11 and vice versa. how to do this? pls help.

//code

```
<li ng-repeat="employee in data.employees">
            <button ng-click="like();">Like</button>

             {{employee.x}}

            <button ng-click="dislike()">Dislike</button>

             {{employee.y}}
          </li>
```

**[samplelink](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fu1UtNclHVo1bj9JGYDq?p=preview)**

Comment: Are you really asking how to do `x=x+1` and `y=y-1`?

Comment: Well, you need to tie the "like"/"dislike" to a user. So, each `employee` record should have a list of users who liked/disliked, and for the current user you need to check whether the user has already liked or disliked a particular employee and handle additional like/dislikes accordingly. At any rate, this is not an Angular question.

Comment: @NewDev forget about each user, i just need to do calculation with these values in my angular app. only to present. not storing these values in any db. only in client side. thank u.

Comment: Then, you need an additional bit of information per each `employee`  record about whether and how current user has voted, and code your `like()` and `dislike()` functions accordingly. You might also consider adding `canLike()` and `canDislike()` to enable/disable the button.

Comment: Dupe : http://i.stack.imgur.com/rGtMH.jpg

Comment: var solid_x = Math.round(wobbly_x);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `liked` and `disliked` properties to each `employee` in the same `ng-click` handlers that add and subtract likes.

```
$scope.like = function(employee){
  employee.x = parseInt(employee.x) + 1;
  if (parseInt(employee.y) > 0)      
    employee.y = parseInt(employee.y) - 1;
  employee.liked = true;
  employee.disliked = false;
}

$scope.dislike = function(employee){
  if (parseInt(employee.x) > 0)      
    employee.x = parseInt(employee.x) - 1;
  employee.y = parseInt(employee.y) + 1;
  employee.liked = false;
  employee.disliked = true;
}
```

Then, `ng-disabled` can prevent additional clicks.

```
<li ng-repeat="employee in data.employees">
  <button ng-click="like(employee)" ng-disabled="employee.liked">Inc</button>
  like: {{employee.x}}

  <button ng-click="dislike(employee)" ng-disabled="employee.disliked">Dec</button>
  dislike: {{employee.y}}
</li>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/qRdp4io5pdfxL7KijTjy?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

it works now..!

```
  <li ng-repeat="employee in data.employees">
    <button ng-disabled="employee.edited" ng-click="like($index);">Inc</button>
    like: {{employee.x}}

    <button ng-disabled="employee.edited" ng-click="dislike($index)">Dec</button>
     dislike: {{employee.y}}
  </li>
```

i added edited property to employee for disable button

```
 $scope.data = {"employees":[
    {"x":"0", "y":"0", 'edited':false}, 
    {"x":"24", "y":"0", 'edited':false}, 
    {"x":"0", "y":"15", 'edited':false}, 
    {"x":"32", "y":"12", 'edited':false}, 
]};


function like(index){
  $scope.data.employees[index].edited = true;
  $scope.data.employees[index].x = parseInt($scope.data.employees[index].x) + 1;   
  if(parseInt($scope.data.employees[index].y) !== 0)
    $scope.data.employees[index].y = parseInt($scope.data.employees[index].y) - 1;

}

function dislike(index){
  $scope.data.employees[index].edited = true;
  if(parseInt($scope.data.employees[index].x) !== 0)
    $scope.data.employees[index].x = parseInt($scope.data.employees[index].x) - 1; 
  $scope.data.employees[index].y = parseInt($scope.data.employees[index].y) + 1;  
}
```

for edited code [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KegMIvSIPejqSSvhmyqz?p=preview)

Comment: can you please give a tick for this answer

Comment: thanks buddy. hope you got the answer you looking for